# C++ Halla el valor minimo que se encuentra en una Matriz

Tags: c++

Tengo un ejercicio que me mandaron de matrices.
El ejercicio me pide que defina y de valores a una matriz de enteros de 5 filas y 4 columnas.
Llame a una función que acepte matrices de tipo entero con 4 columnas (cantidad de filas a pasar como parámetro) y devuelva en que fila y columna se encuentra el menor elemento de una matriz.
El tema es que no pude resolver el ejercicio y me fije el código que había enviado el profesor resuelto pero ahora que lo pase a la ID me tira error o cualquier cosa .

### Código del profesor :

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void mostrarmat(int m[][4],int dfil){
   const int dcol=4;
   for(int i=0;i<dfil;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<dcol;i++){
         cout<<m[i][j]<<endl;
      }
   }
}
void menor(int m[][4],int dfil, int& mfil, int& mcol){
   mfil=0;
   mcol=0;
   const int dcol=4;

   for(int i=0;i<dfil;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<dcol;i++){
        if ((m[i][j])<(m[mfil][mcol]))
        {mfil=i;
         mcol=j;
        }
        }
   }
}
int main(){
const int nfil=5;
const int ncol=4;
int mat[nfil][ncol]={25,8 ,12,7,
                      17,11,9 ,33,
                      21,3 ,41,5,
                      4 ,34,92,18,
                      37,6 ,43,54};
 cout<<"Datos:"<<endl;
 mostrarmat(mat,nfil);
 int fpos,cpos;
 menor(mat,nfil,fpos,cpos);
 cout<<endl<<"El menor valor es"<<mat[fpos][cpos];
 cout<<"y se encuentra en la fila"<<fpos<<"y la columna";
 cout<<cpos<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

PD: Este es mi primer post en la pagina si llegue a cometer algún tipo de error al hacer la publicación, sugiero que me lo digan, desde ya también espero a aportar a esta comunidad con los conocimientos que voy adquiriendo.

Comment: Hola J.Guillen, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cuál es la pregunta concreta o el error concreto que tienes? Para empezar y a simple vista hay un error tonto pero muy trascendente ya que terminas con un ciclo infinito y accediendo a memoria que no deberías, en el segundo for anidado a la hora de recorrer el array. Tienes `for(int j=0;j<dcol;i++)`, con lo que incrementas en el for anidado la variable de control del primero... debe ser `for(int j=0; j<dcol; j++)`

Comment: En concreto ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

los errores que cometiste son varios, la **declaración de la matriz** no tiene una **sintaxis correcta**, en los **FOR** de la variable **j** haces un incremento a la variable **i**.

estás usando **dos variables** que ya están declaradas en otro módulo fpos, cpos<>/kbd.

más abajo te dejo el código modificado con comentarios por si no entiendes muy bien los errores que digo. Las variables globales serian mas eficientes pero también la puedes hacer con el método que pusiste.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ffpos=0, ccpos=0; //Declaramos las variables de forma global para poder usarlas en todas las funciones/eventos y cambiamos de fpos a ffpos y de cpos a ccpos un modulo ya contiene estas variables en uso

void mostrarmat(int m[][4],int dfil){
    const int dcol=4;
    for(int i=0;i<dfil;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<dcol;j++){ //El incremento se le aria a la variable j
            cout<<m[i][j];
            (j!=dcol-1)?cout<<"\t":cout<<"\n"; //Solo agrego esta linea para que la salida sea mucho mas intuitiva
        }
    }
}
void menor(int m[][4], int dfil){
    /*mfil=0; 
    mcol=0;*/ //Usaremos las variables globales fpos y ccpos
    const int dcol=4;

    for(int i=0;i<dfil;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<dcol;j++){ //El incremento se le aria a la variable j.
            if ((m[i][j])<(m[ffpos][ccpos])){
                ffpos=i;
                ccpos=j;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    const int nfil=5;
    const int ncol=4;
    //La sitaxis de una matriz seria la siguiente.
    int mat[nfil][ncol] = {
    {25,8 ,12,7},
    {17,11,9 ,33},
    {21,3 ,41,5},
    {4 ,34,92,18},
    {37,6 ,43,54}
    };
    cout<<"Matriz:"<<endl<<endl;
    mostrarmat(mat, nfil); //Eliminamos los parametros que no usamos
    /*int ffpos,ccpos;*/ //Esta linea ya no es necesaria.
    menor(mat,nfil);
    cout<<endl<<"El menor valor es "<<mat[ffpos][ccpos]; //Faltaban unos espacios para que la salida estubiera bien
    cout<<" y se encuentra en la fila "<<ffpos<<" y la columna "<<ccpos<<endl; //Faltaban unos espacios para que la salida estubiera bien
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buenisimo me ayudaste mucho. Gracias :D